# Speed up nested apply code in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, lapply

I have a large dataframe in R containing 2 columns (A sample with a and b below).

```
set.seed(12);n =5;n_a=5;n_b=5
id_lengths = sample(1:n,n_a,replace=T)
a = rep(1:n_a,id_lengths)
b = sample(1:n_b,length(a),replace =T)
data = data.frame(a = a,b = b)
```

I want to get a sorted vector of unique values in column "a" for each "a". This vector should be sorted by the maximum overlapping based on column "b". I am using the below code to achieve the results.

```
get_similar_ids = function(z){
    tmp = sapply(a_list,FUN = function(z1){length(intersect(z1,z))})
    sort(tmp,decreasing=T)
}
a_list = split(data$b,data$a)
lapply(a_list,FUN=get_similar_ids)
```

Results:

```
$`1`
1 2 3 4 5
1 1 0 0 0

$`2`
2 1 3 5 4
3 1 1 1 0

$`3`
3 2 4 1 5
3 1 1 0 0

$`4`
3 4 1 2 5
1 1 0 0 0

$`5`
2 5 1 3 4
1 1 0 0 0
```

The problem is the actual data has a large n_a (~1700000),n_b (~250000) and n(~15) resulting in a data of rows more than 13 million and this code is not at all replicable for such large values.
Any ideas how to speed up these operations??

Comment: You describe "I want to get a sorted vector of unique values in column "a" for each "a"". Your data only have one row for `a == 1` but your first list element has entries for both 1 and 2. Is this correct? If not, then you can further simplify James's solution.

Comment: Yes, both 1 and 2 should have entries in the first list element, because a==1 and a==2 have 1 common b (b=1).

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain your desired output data with some simple linear algebra on tabluations of your original data:

```
(x <- with(data,(table(a,b)>0) %*% (table(b,a)>0)))
   a
a   1 2 3 4 5
  1 1 1 0 0 0
  2 1 3 1 0 1
  3 0 1 3 1 0
  4 0 0 1 1 0
  5 0 1 0 0 1
```

Then it is just a matter of sorting it how you want:

```
lapply(unique(data$a), function(y) sort(x[,y],decreasing=TRUE))
[[1]]
1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 0 0 0 

[[2]]
2 1 3 5 4 
3 1 1 1 0 

[[3]]
3 2 4 1 5 
3 1 1 0 0 

[[4]]
3 4 1 2 5 
1 1 0 0 0 

[[5]]
2 5 1 3 4 
1 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.I have made an edit in the question to make the sample dataset closer to the real data which I am using. In the actual data the number of unique values in column "a" are around 1.7 million and in column "b" 0.25 million. Due to this R is unable to make a 1.7M X 1.7M matrix giving the error : "Error in table(a, b) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"

Comment: You are going to have that many elements in your output, so you are going to have issues with those numbers which ever way you approach it. Storage of the output alone will be 10-20Tb depending on if integers can be used. I suspect the matrix would be sparse, so you may be able to use a sparse matrix implementation to help, but the list representation of the data would still require the larger storage space.

Comment: If the result is likely to be sparse, then do try my _merge_ approach below, as it will omit the empty intersections from the start.  If not, are you really sure you want to quantify all the entries, or will a heuristic do to get the top few pairs of `a` - you can find the most common `b`s and restrict yourself to `a`s that contain those, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bit of a speed-up by removing duplicate rows of *data*, as `intersect` operates on sets, so will not count mulitple instances of the same *b* within *a*.  Depending on what large n means (more rows, more distinct a's, more distinct b's,...?) an alternative approach is to generate all overlaps by:

```
d2 <- data[!duplicated(data),]
mer <- merge(d2, d2, by="b")
table(paste0(d2$a.x, d2$a.y))
```

which will give you the a-coordinates of all the non-zero overlaps.  Or `table(d2$a.x, d2$a.y)` which you can then sort per row.